# How to fetch values that are hard coded in a Perl subroutine?

Tags: perl

I have a perl code like this:

```
use constant OPERATING_MODE_MAIN_ADMIN  => 'super_admin';
use constant OPERATING_MODE_ADMIN       => 'admin';
use constant OPERATING_MODE_USER        => 'user';
sub system_details
{
    return {
        operating_modes => {
            values => [OPERATING_MODE_MAIN_ADMIN, OPERATING_MODE_ADMIN, OPERATING_MODE_USER],
            help   => {
                'super_admin'  => 'The system displays the settings for super admin',
                'admin' => 'The system displays settings for normal admin',
                'user' => 'No settings are displayed. Only user level pages.'
            }
        },
        log_level => {
            values => [qw(FATAL ERROR WARN INFO DEBUG TRACE)],
            help   => "http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.49/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm#Log_Levels"
        },
    };
}
```

How will I access the "value" fields and "help" fields of each key from another subroutine? Suppose I want the values of operating_mode alone or log_level alone?

Comment: Do you mean how to access them when you call the sub and get what it returns? The title is unclear.

Comment: Yes. That's the issue.

Comment: Then which "values" do you want?  Your `log_level` hashref has an arrayref "value" for one key but a string for the other.

Comment: I need to access both. I need to fetch the values and help keys of operating_mode as well as log_level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `system_details()` returns a hashref, which has two keys with values being hashrefs. So you can dereference the sub's return and assign into a hash, and then extract what you need

```
my %sys = %{ system_details() };

my @loglevel_vals = @{ $sys{log_level}->{values} };

my $help_msg = $sys{log_level}->{help};
```

The `@loglevel_vals` array contains `FATAL`, `ERROR` etc, while `$help_msg` has the message string.

This makes an extra copy of a hash while one can work with a reference, as in [doimen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50943771/4653379)

```
my $sys = system_details();
my @loglevel_vals = @{ $sys->{log_level}->{values} };
```

But as the purpose is to interrogate the data in another sub it also makes sense to work with a local copy, what is generally safer (against accidentally changing data in the caller).

There are modules that help with deciphering complex data structures, by displaying them.  This helps devising ways to work with data. Often quoted is [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html), which also does more than show data.  Some of the others are meant to simply display the data. A couple of nice ones are [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Data-Dump-1.23/lib/Data/Dump.pm) and [Data::Printer](http://search.cpan.org/~garu/Data-Printer-0.40/lib/Data/Printer.pm).

Comment: Thank you @zdim . I know Data Dumper and use it frequently. Here my objective is to return the values to another sub routine to validate the values entered from php front end.

Comment: @Phoenix Ah, OK.  Then your sub is written accordingly -- its return is a scalar (hashref), easy and nice to pass around. Then in the other sub you can dereference, etc.

Comment: Yup :)  Thanks for the quick response and help.

Comment: Why copy the hash (`my %sys = %{ system_details() };`) instead of just using the referfence?

Comment: @ikegami  There wasn't a special reason (except that at first I wasn't sure what was wanted, given the title).  But it turned out reasonable, since the purpose is to do this in another sub, to check; then it is generally safer to have a local copy.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $sys = system_details;
my $log_level = $sys->{'log_level'};

my @values = @{ $log_level->{'values'} };
my $help = $log_level->{'help'};
```

If you need to introspect the type of structure stored in help (for example `help` in `operating_mode` is a hash, but in `log_level` it is a string), use the [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#ref-EXPR)  builtin func.

Comment: Thank you for answering.